# Gravar tela com ffmpeg

Tags: linux

Qual o comando do ffmpeg que grava a tela do computador, pois antes tinha um comando via linha de comando que fazia essa gravação sem precisar de outro software, apenas o ffmpeg puro.

Comment: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/Desktop

Answer (score 2):

Que tal:

```
$ ffmpeg -f x11grab -s 1280x720 -r 25 -i :0.0 -q:v 5 video.mkv
```

Onde:

```
$ ffmpeg -f x11grab -s <Resolucao> -r <Quadros Por Segundo> -i :0.0 -q:v <Qualidade de Video 1-5> <Arquivo de Saida>
```